# jQuery does not bring the contents of a form element if inside a table element on an ajax load

Tags: jquery

I'm a bit new to ajax and am strugging with a few things I can't figure out...including this one that does not load a table element when there is a form element in it. Any ideas?

for the main page, called TESTajax.php I have these:

```
$("a").live('click',(function(e){ 
    var linkurl = $(this).attr('href');
    $("#main").load(linkurl);
    e.preventDefault();
}));
```

```
<a href="TESTajax.html">Test</a><div id="main">/div>
```

And for the page that is to be loaded, TESTajax.html, I have:

```
<div>
    <div id="content">
        <h1>Can you see me now?</h1>
        <table>
            <thead></thead>
            <tfoot></tfoot>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <form>
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="1"/>
                        <td>Value1</td>
                        <td><button>Submit</button></td>
                    </form>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <form>
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="2"/>
                        <td>Value2</td>
                        <td><button>Submit</button></td>
                    </form>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

When the page loads, the H1 comes over but nothing else.

If I remove the table and make everything a list (UL and LI instead of TABLE and TR) it displays everything.

If I remove the form tags, it displays everything.

I'm quite confused and really do like have those form tags there as my existing code is all designed to work with it and I'd really like to use a table because there are about 15 data columns that are best presented as a table.

Thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have a `<form>` directly inside a `<tr>`, so the invalid HTML is probably being tossed.

Given your `<form>` and input elements, it looks like this layout for a row would work:

```
<tr>
   <td>Value1</td>
   <td>
     <form>
       <input type="hidden" name="id" value="1"/>
       <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Alternatively if you're submitting via AJAX, you could serialize the row yourself, but this approach won't degrade well, so I'd advise against it when possible.  IMO `<form>` tags *should* be able to encapsulate a row, it'd be tremendously handy, unfortunately that's not the case.

Comment: You are absolutely right, the form can't go in a TR, fascinating. And that would be very useful. I just did a quick test and the form can't go inside TABLE or TBODY either, it needs to be within the TD or outside of TABLE. Oh well. At least I know the problem and I'll go write some what I consider sloppy but technically correct code. Thanks for the quick and accurate response!