# How to resolve strange conflict between form post and ajax post?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

On the one page, I am trying to use ajax to edit existing values. I am doing this by using [jQuery Inline Edit](http://www.labs.mimmin.com/inlineedit/) and posting away the new data, updating the record and returning with success.

This is working fine.

Next I have implemented the ability to add new records, to do this I have a form at the end of the table, which submits post data then redirects back to the original page.

Each of them work individually, but after I have used the form to add a new record, the inline editing stops to work. If I close the webpage and reopen it, it works fine again until I have used the form and it goes of the rails again.

I have tried a number of solutions, clearing session data, giving the form a separate name, redirecting to an alternative page (which does work, but is not ideal as I want the form to redirect back to the original location ).

Here is a sample of the view form data:

```
<?php foreach($week->incomes as $income):?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $income->name;?></td>
        <td width="70" style="text-align:right;" class="editableSingle income id<?php echo $income->id;?>">$<?php echo $income->cost;?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach;?>
    <?php echo form_open('budget/add/'.$week->id.'/income/index', 'class="form-vertical" id="add_income"'); ?>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="name" class="input-small" placeholder="Name">
            <input type="text" name="cost" class="input-small" placeholder="Cost">
        </td>
        <td>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-small pull-right"><i class="icon-plus "></i></button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

This is the javascript initialisation code:

```
$(function(){
$.inlineEdit({
    income: 'budget/update_income/',
    expense: 'budget/update_expense/'
}, 
{
    animate: false,
    filterElementValue: function($o){

        if ($o.hasClass('income')) {
            return $o.html().match(/\$(.+)/)[1];
        }
        else if ($o.hasClass('expense')) {
            return $o.html().match(/\$(.+)/)[1];
        }
        else {
            return $o.html();
        }
    }, 
    afterSave: function(o){
        if (o.type == 'income') {
            $('.income.id' + o.id).prepend('$');
        }
        if (o.type == 'expense') {
            $('.expense.id' + o.id).prepend('$');
        }
    },
    colors: { error:'green' }
});
});
```

If I can provide any more information to clarify what I have attempted etc, let me know.

**Temporary Fix**

It seems I have come up with a work around, not ideal as I still am not sure what is causing the issue.

I have created a method called redirect.

```
public function redirect(){
    redirect('');
}
```

am now calling that after the form submit which has temporarily allows my multiple post submits to work.

Comment: Can you post the part that you initialize javascript

Comment: Have you checked the Firebug console for any error after the form submit? You can also check if the code "$.inlineEdit({...})" is being executed or not after regular form submit.

Comment: Nothing seems to appear in the console area. I'm beginning to isolate the issue down to the redirect() method. After redirect it no longer lets me use the inline editor.

Comment: try ctrl+shift+j for console errors. Also the inlin editing you are using clone it with other unique id and fill it with the newly data and see if it still works

Comment: Are you using the same controller and method for both actions? Just curious.

Comment: Also, have you tried changing the HTML markup so it is valid? A `<form>` tag really shouldn't open between `<tr>`'s, it may be worth checking if some issue is coming from there. Also, why is the `filterElementValue()` function using a param with the dollar sign included, while the `afterSave()` isn't? Is this something to do with the `InlineEdit` plugin? Could also do with seeing some controllers, there might be something fishy in there (hopefully not! :))

Comment: Hey Oliver, have you had any progress with this? I have few ideas i can test out before answering, if you still need some help

Comment: Sorry for lack of response, haven't had a chance to get on the internet, I have found the issue and resolved it again, somewhat temporarily. I'll post my discoveries tomorrow morning when I'm free.

Comment: I did some digging into the javascript file of the inline edit thing and found that the ajax was posting to the index controller method instead of the 'update_incomes' method. I'm still not sure why. I have set up a condition on the index method to check to see if there is post data, and if there is to redirect to the correct method based on that data.

Answer (score 0):

please try and see by replacing the jquery sign.

**$** should be replaced by **jQuery** then it will create new instance to work fine

Answer (score 0):

I heard somewhere that jquery wont work if you put the form inside the table tag.
It need to be outside the table as in:

```
<form>
<table>
...
</table>
</form>
```

[jQuery does not bring the contents of a form element if inside a table element on an ajax load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626831/jquery-does-not-bring-the-contents-of-a-form-element-if-inside-a-table-element-o)

After testing it, i've discover that it is partialy true, (aka un-reliable)... It's the reason why i stopped using tables.

Comment: hmm, i'll have a look into my code to see if this makes a difference. Thanks :)